# Linq query doesn't support System.String

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

First of all, I have seen questions similar to this, but I've not resolve my problem for this reason I am asking here.

I am working with SQL Server and I'd like to transform from LINQ to SQL, in C#.
This is my table:
[image]

This is my code:

```
  [Table]  public class h
    {

       [Column] public string username;
       [Column(IsPrimaryKey =true)] public string password;
       [Column] public int id; 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bsdDataContext cc = new bsdDataContext("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=toolsdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=0359");

            Table<h> h_table = cc.GetTable<h>();

            IQueryable<string> query = from item in h_table where item.username.Contains('o') orderby item.username.Length select item.username.ToString();

            foreach (string item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

And when I build my program I get the error, **System.NotSupportedException: '**, String operators for type 'System.String' are not supported.
[image]

Comment: Password as primary key?

Comment: @RubensFarias Yes, because I am going to store the passwords with a MD5 encode, and I don't want duplicate passwords... ID is an auto increment field so I am not very sure if I have to mark this like a primary key also.

Comment: I'd change the primary key to the ID field. There can only be one Primary Key. Also, the MD5 hashing algorythm isn't the most secure way of storing passwords.

Comment: @Reynevan I will use sha256 better...

Comment: @JoseAviles Give this a shot: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

If you want maximum security this might be worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `Contains()` overload that takes a `char`.

That's probably confusing the LINQ engine.

Change `'` to `"` so that you're passing a `string` and it should work.

Also, don't call `.ToString()`; that's probably also messing it up.

Comment: Omg I feel me so embarrassed, I've been at least 1h searching about my problem, thx! Then I've seen that I can't use orderby username.Length...

Answer (score 0):

contains always finding string value

```
    IQueryable<string> query = from item in h_table where item.username.Contains('o') orderby item.username.Length select item.username.ToString();
```

replace above with

```
    IQueryable<string> query = from item in h_table where item.username.Contains("o") orderby item.username.Length select item.username;
```